# How to prove monotonic transformation of the function and equivalence?

Tags: microeconomics, utility

At the microeconomics course I have to prove monotonic transformation of the function

U(x,y) = A(x^a)(y^b)

into

U(x,y) = (x^0.5)(y^0.5)

Since the MRS are ay/bx and x/y resp. I can obviously only prove that the transformaton isn't monotonic.

But the ordinal equivalence seems to be impossible to prove without having certain x & y values at which I would compute the utility levels for each function. Is it possible to derive a general proof that I don't know?

Comment: What's the question again? You said, "I have to prove monotonic transformation of the function ... into ..." but I don't think that's a complete sentence.

Comment: Yes, that's all. I assume the type of transformation is the unspecified one that transforms the first function into the second one.